# How to write to variables passed to the Variadic function in C

Tags: c, pointers, stdin, variadic-functions

I'm totally new to C and I'm wondering is it possible to create a variadic function and pass pointers of variables into it and write data into the variables?

One obvious example of what I'm looking for is the `scanf` function which takes the input from the stdin and writes it into the variables.

Here is a sample of want I want to do:

```
void fun(int num, ...){
//    insert 2 in a and "abc" in b
}

int main(void){
    int a;
    char *b;
    fun(2, &a, &b);
}
```

**update** I can alter my constructor to get variables pattern instead of the number of them, so here is the code after modification:

```
void fun(char *fmt, ...){
//    insert 2 in a and "abc" in b
}

int main(void){
    int a;
    char *b;
    fun("dc", &a, &b);
}
```

Comment: The thing is how to know the type of these variable.

Comment: I can assure you it's possible, but you will learn more if you work it out for youself. First, figure out how you would write this function if it _wasn't_ variadic. Then think about what you would have to change to make it variadic.  Also, maybe you haven't discovered [`stdarg.h`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic) yet?  You need that.

Comment: Remember that `scanf()` and family have the format string to guide them as to what types are present in the variable argument list.  On the face of it, your `2` in the call identifies two variables (pointers), but there is no type information. You need to know (somehow) the types of the pointers. (I learned to program in C on a machine where the `char *` value for a given memory location was different from the `int *` address for the same memory location — I am sensitive to problems in this area, even 30 years later.) You might decide to use a string instead of a count: `fun("i s", &a, &b)`.

Comment: Why don't you look at the source of `scanf`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for your comment, I update the question

Comment: The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49313605/15168) by [Nominal Animal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1475978/nominal-animal) does essentially what I suggested and meets your modified specification pretty well.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I tried that but the problem is when I alter `s1` to some new value like `"hello"` in the `foo` function and print the value of `s1` in the main function after `foo`, it still prints `"First"`. they have different memory addresses

Comment: Hmmm...the given answer is concerned with the printing side (accessing the variables in the variadic function) rather than the scanning side (modifying the variables in the calling code).  If no-one else has done so, I'll do something in the morning — I need to sleep now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start with the example code shown in the [stdarg man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdarg.3.html) (`man 3 stdarg`). Slightly modified for readability, and adding a trivial `main()`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(char *fmt, ...)
{
   va_list ap;
   int d;
   char c, *s;

   va_start(ap, fmt);

   while (*fmt) {
       switch (*(fmt++)) {

       case 's':
           s = va_arg(ap, char *);
           printf("string %s\n", s);
           break;

       case 'd':
           d = va_arg(ap, int);
           printf("int %d\n", d);
           break;

       case 'c':
           /* need a cast here since va_arg only
              takes fully promoted types */
           c = (char) va_arg(ap, int);
           printf("char %c\n", c);
           break;
       }
   }

   va_end(ap);
}


int main(void)
{
    char *s1 = "First";
    char *s2 = "Second";
    int   d = 42;
    char  c = '?';

    foo("sdcs", s1, d, c, s2);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you compile and run the above, it will output

```
string First
int 42
char ?
string Second
```

As liliscent and Jonathan Leffler commented to the question, the key point is that we need a way to describe the *type* of each variadic argument. (In C, type information is essentially discarded at compile time, so if we want to support multiple types for one argument, we must also pass its type explicitly: the type (of a variadic function argument) simply does not exist at run time anymore.)

Above, the first parameter, `fmt`, is a string where each character describes one variadic argument (by describing its type). Thus, there are expected to be the same number of variadic arguments as there are `s`, `d`, or `c` characters in the `fmt` string.

The [printf family of functions](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) and the [scanf family of functions](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) both use `%` to indicate a variadic argument, followed by the formatting details and type specification of that argument. Because of the quite complex formatting they support, the code implementing those is much more complicated than the above example, but the logic is very much the same.

---

In an update to the question, OP asked if the function can change the value  of the variadic arguments -- or rather, the values pointed to by the variadic arguments, similar to how [scanf()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) family of functions work.

Because parameters are passed by value, and `va_arg()` yields the value of the parameter, and not a reference to the parameter, any modifications we make to the value itself locally (to `s`, `d`, or  `c` in the `foo()` function example above) will not be visible to the caller. However, if we pass pointers to the values -- just like `scanf()` functions do --, we can modify the values the pointers point to.

Consider a slightly modified version of the above `foo()` function, `zero()`:

```
void zero(char *fmt, ...)
{
   va_list ap;
   int *d;
   char *c, **s;

   va_start(ap, fmt);

   while (*fmt) {
       switch (*(fmt++)) {

       case 's':
           s = va_arg(ap, char **);
           if (s)
               *s = NULL;
           break;

       case 'd':
           d = va_arg(ap, int *);
           if (d)
               *d = 0;
           break;

       case 'c':
           /* pointers are fully promoted */
           c = va_arg(ap, char *);
           if (c)
               *c = 0;
           break;
       }
   }

   va_end(ap);
}
```

Note the differences to `foo()`, especially in the `va_arg()` expressions. (I would also suggest renaming `d`, `c`, and `s` to `dptr`, `cptr`, and `sptr`, respectively, to help remind us humans reading the code that they are no longer the values themselves, but pointers to the values we wish to modify. I omitted this change to keep the function as similar to `foo()` as possible, to keep it easy to compare the two functions.)

With this, we can do for example

```
    int d = 5;
    char *p = "z";

    zero("ds", &d, &p);
```

and `d` will be cleared to zero, and `p` to be `NULL`.

We are not limited to a single `va_arg()` within each case, either. We can, for example, modify the above to take two parameters per formatting letter, with the first being a pointer to the parameter, and the second the value:

```
void let(char *fmt, ...)
{
   va_list ap;
   int *dptr, d;
   char *cptr, c, **sptr, *s;

   va_start(ap, fmt);

   while (*fmt) {
       switch (*(fmt++)) {

       case 's':
           sptr = va_arg(ap, char **);
           s = va_arg(ap, char *);
           if (sptr)
               *sptr = s;
           break;

       case 'd':
           dptr = va_arg(ap, int *);
           d = va_arg(ap, int);
           if (dptr)
               *dptr = d;
           break;

       case 'c':
           cptr = va_arg(ap, char *);
           /* a 'char' type variadic argument
              is promoted to 'int' in C: */
           c = (char) va_arg(ap, int);
           if (cptr)
               *cptr = c;
           break;
       }
   }

   va_end(ap);
}
```

This last function you can use via e.g.

```
int a;
char *b;

let("ds", &a, 2, &b, "abc");
```

which has the same effect as `a = 2; b = "abc";`. Note that we do not modify the data `b` points to; we just set `b` to point to a literal string `abc`.

---

In C11 and later, there is a `_Generic` keyword (see e.g. [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9804402/1475978)), that can be used in conjunction with preprocessor macros, to choose between expressions depending on the type(s) of the argument(s).

Because it does not exist in earlier versions of the standards, we now have to use for example `sin()`, `sinf()`, and `sinl()` to return the sine of their argument, depending on whether the argument (and desired result) is a `double`, `float`, or a `long double`. In C11, we can define

```
#define Sin(x) _Generic((x),               \
                        long double: sinl, \
                        float: sinf,       \
                        default: sin)(x)
```

so that we can just call `Sin(x)`, with the compiler choosing the proper function variant: `Sin(1.0f)` is equivalent to `sinf(1.0f)`, and `Sin(1.0)` is equivalent to `sin(1.0)`, for example.

(Above, the `_Generic()` expression evaluates to one of `sinl`, `sinf`, or `sin`; the final `(x)` makes the macro evaluate to a function call with the macro parameter `x` as the function parameter.)

This is not a contradiction to the earlier section of this answer. Even when using the `_Generic` keyword, the types are checked at compile time. It is basically just [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) on top of macro parameter type comparison checking, that helps writing type-specific code; in other words, a kind of a switch..case statement that acts on preprocessor macro parameter *types*, calling exactly one function in each case.

Furthermore, `_Generic` does not really work with variadic functions. In particular, you cannot do the selection based on any variadic arguments to those functions.

However, the macros used can easily look like variadic functions. If you want to explore such generics a bit further, see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35168773/1475978) "answer" I wrote some time ago.

Comment: I update my question, now is it possible to change the value of `s1` in the `foo` function?

Comment: @Yashar: See the added section in the middle. Let me know if it does not clear it up for you.

Comment: Now that's an answer `:)`